# Compare directories and sub directories and replace files based on MD5 hash

Tags: powershell, md5

Have a comparison script that compares based on MD5 hash. Noticed that it's doing odd things.

```
 $Source=  "D:\Folder1"
$Destination = "D:\folder2"

get-childitem $Source -Recurse | foreach {
 #Calculate hash using Algorithm MD5 reference http://www.tomsitpro.com/articles/powershell-file-hash-check,2-880.html
 Write-Host "Copying $($_.fullname) to $Destination" -ForegroundColor Yellow
 $OriginalHash = Get-FileHash -Path $_.FullName -Algorithm MD5

 #Now copy what's different
 $replacedfile = $_ | Copy-Item -Destination $Destination -Force -PassThru

 #Check the hash sum of the file copied
 $copyHash = Get-FileHash -Path $replacedfile.FullName -Algorithm MD5

 #compare them up
 if ($OriginalHash.hash -ne $copyHash.hash) {
    Write-Warning "$($_.Fullname) and $($replacedfile.fullname) Files don't match!" 
 }
 else {
    Write-Host "$($_.Fullname) and $($replacedfile.fullname) Files Match" -ForegroundColor Green
 }
} #Win!
```

The script works fine, until it finds a difference in a sub folder. It then for some reason i can't seem to find, it copies the different item to BOTH the top level and the sub level.....I am being really dumb and I can't see the issue, need a second pair of eyes.

Example

```
File Test.Txt is in Source\SubFolder
```

Script runs and puts Test.Txt in Destination\Subfolder AND Destination.....

Any ideas?

Comment: Why trying to rewrite a subdirectory diff tool? Just use one that already exists.

Comment: Obviously need to, or I wouldn't be doing this. I won't go into detail as it's irrelevant to the issue. Just take my word for it, I need to do it like this.

Comment: Are you sure you don't have `-Recurse` enabled on your `Copy-Item` command?  The only way I could recreate your output was when I recursively copied the file.

Comment: Not that I know of, the script is as it is. The surrounding function just unzips a file, no copy item. I can replicate this by simplifying this significantly. 


        param(
    [string]$s = 'D:\folder1',
    [string]$t = 'D:\Folder2'
)
 
$target = Get-ChildItem $t -Recurse
$source = get-childitem $s -Recurse
Compare-Object $source $target -Property Name, length -PassThru |
    Where-Object { $_.SideIndicator -eq '<=' } |
    foreach-object -Process{
        copy-item $_.FullName -destination $t
        }

Comment: The line ` $replacedfile = $_ |` is your fault, here `$_` contains only the name without the subdir, and is copied to `$Destination`.

Answer (score 1):

The line `$replacedfile = $_ |` is a fault, here $_ contains only the name without the subdir, and is copied to $Destination.

Replace the line:

```
$replacedfile = $_ | Copy-Item -Destination $Destination -Force -PassThru
```

with:

```
$replacedfile = $_.Fullname -replace [RegEx]::escape($Source),$Destination
```

This replaces the differing base part leaving the curent source sub dir intact.
The [RegEx]::escape($Source) is necessary because the source string contains
backslashes which would be interpreted as an escape char by the replace function.

**EDIT** Complete script to avoid ambiguities:

```
$Source=  "D:\Folder1"
$Destination = "D:\folder2"

get-childitem $Source -Recurse | foreach {
    #Calculate hash using Algorithm MD5 reference http://www.tomsitpro.com/articles/powershell-file-hash-check,2-880.html
    $SrcFile = $_.FullName
    $SrcHash = Get-FileHash -Path $SrcFile -Algorithm MD5

    $DestFile = $_.Fullname -replace [RegEx]::escape($Source),$Destination
    Write-Host "Copying $SrcFile to $DestFile" -ForegroundColor Yellow

    if (Test-Path $DestFile) {
        #Check the hash sum of the file copied
        $DestHash = Get-FileHash -Path $DestFile -Algorithm MD5

        #compare them up
        if ($SrcHash.hash -ne $DestHash.hash) {
            Write-Warning "$SrcFile and $DestFile Files don't match!" 
            Copy-Item $SrcFile -Destination $DestFile -Force
        } else {
            Write-Host "$SrcFile and $DestFile Files Match" -ForegroundColor Green
        }
    } else {
        Copy-Item $SrcFile -Destination $DestFile -Force
    }
}
```

Comment: OK i see the logic, but this breaks the script.

Get-FileHash : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null.
At line:15 char:33
+  $copyHash = Get-FileHash -Path $replacedfile.FullName -Algorithm MD5
+                                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Get-FileHash], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Get-FileHash'

Comment: @RichardDakin $replacedfile was  a string not an object, so lateron references have to omit the `.Fullname` Rewrote the script above.

Comment: Sorry taken so long to reply. There is a typo in your above script also. Replace should be -replace. This does appear to solve the issue however. Thank you.