# Compare two bmp files with Get-FileHash

Tags: powershell

I have a script which compare two images by their file hash:

```
if((Get-FileHash C:\Users\UserName\Desktop\OrImg).hash -ne (Get-FileHash C:\Users\UserName\Desktop\RefImg).hash)
{"Files are different"}
else {"Files are the same"}
```

But how can I be sure that two images are different by hash property? For test purpose I have created two different images (size, content) but when I compared them - hash was the same. Maybe I am doing something wrong?

Comment: I don't see any errors in your code, this should work!

Comment: "I have created two different images (size, content) but when I compared them - HASH was the same." - No you did not. That's literally a 1 in 340282366920938463463374607431768211456 chance

Comment: @MartinBrandl My mistake. I have compared two HASHes of folder not files inside folders. `$varf1 = Get-ChildItem "Path_To_The_Folder" -Recurse | foreach {Get-FileHash -Path $_.FullName}` - that how can HASH of files inside folder can be compared.

Comment: Just iterate over the files from one folder and use your snippet above (the other file must be loaded from the second dir)

Comment: @MartinBrandl Yeap, I have done it already. `(Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $refbmp -DifferenceObject $orbmp -Property hash -PassThru).Path`

Now I see the difference between files. Ok, but I would like to put it into if statement. For example if files are different Write-Output File name_of_the_file in dir 1 is different than name_of_the_file in dir 2 (file name is the same for both files). How I can do it?

Comment: @mikhail-r, Is this kind of comparison fast enough?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will return all files with different file hash. Note: This will not check whether the file exists in directory two nor does it check whether directory two contains files that directory one doesn't.

```
$leftDir = "D:\tmp\1"
$rightDir = "D:\tmp\2"

$differentFiles = Get-ChildItem $leftDir | Where-Object {
    ($_ | Get-FileHash).Hash -ne (Get-FileHash (Join-Path $rightDir $_.Name)).Hash
} 

if (-not $differentFiles)
{
    'All files are the same'
}
else
{
    $differentFiles | Foreach-Object {Write-Output "File $($_.Name) is different"}
}
```

Comment: Great, Martin! It's almost what I need. But how can I add result of the script and parse it to Write-Output "Files are the same" if all files are the same or Write-Output "Files $nameofthefile(s) is(are) different"?

Comment: Fantastic, Martin! But let's imagine that all files in both folders are the same and I would to write - if (your function above) - all files in both folders are the same - write-output "All files are the same". 

If (your function above) - some files in both folder are different - write-output "File $($_.Name) is different"?

Comment: Super cool! Martin thank you so much for your help. I am learning PS but some cases are pretty tough.

Answer (score 1):

I asked the same sort of question regarding a script I'd written that did half the job. Here is the finished article.

Reference here [Compare directories and sub directories and replace files based on MD5 hash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41876703/compare-directories-and-sub-directories-and-replace-files-based-on-md5-hash)

Thanks to @LotPings for his help

```
$Source=  "D:\Folder1"
$Destination = "D:\folder2"

get-childitem $Source -Recurse | foreach {
#Calculate hash using Algorithm MD5 reference http://www.tomsitpro.com/articles/powershell-file-hash-check,2-880.html
$SrcFile = $_.FullName
$SrcHash = Get-FileHash -Path $SrcFile -Algorithm MD5

$DestFile = $_.Fullname -replace [RegEx]::escape($Source),$Destination
Write-Host "Copying $SrcFile to $DestFile" -ForegroundColor Yellow

if (Test-Path $DestFile) {
    #Check the hash sum of the file copied
    $DestHash = Get-FileHash -Path $DestFile -Algorithm MD5

    #compare them up
    if ($SrcHash.hash -ne $DestHash.hash) {
        Write-Warning "$SrcFile and $DestFile Files don't match!" 
        Copy-Item $SrcFile -Destination $DestFile -Force
    } else {
        Write-Host "$SrcFile and $DestFile Files Match" -ForegroundColor Green
    }
} else {
    Copy-Item $SrcFile -Destination $DestFile -Force
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

I did this Windows PowerShell with md5 sum for my test script. it is working fine for me.

```
    $FilePathSource = "C:\Susantha\Test.txt"
    $FilePathDestination = "C:\Susantha\Test.txt"

    try
    {
    $md5 = New-Object -TypeName System.Security.Cryptography.MD5CryptoServiceProvider
    $hashedFileSource = [System.BitConverter]::ToString($md5.ComputeHash([System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes($FilePathSource)))
    $hashedFileDestination = [System.BitConverter]::ToString($md5.ComputeHash([System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes($FilePathDestination)))

    [bool]$Result = $hashedFileSource.CompareTo($hashedFileDestination)

      if ($Result) {
       Write-Host "Not the Same Files :("
       }
      else{
       Write-Host "Same Files :)"
       }
   }
   catch
   {
   Write-Host  $_.Exception.Message
   Write-Host $_.Exception.ItemName
   Break
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$x = (Get-FileHash 'C:\temp\1.bmp').hash
$z = (Get-FileHash 'C:\temp\2.bmp').hash
[bool]$w = $z.CompareTo($x)
if ($w) {
Write-Host "Not the same"
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but it's about one two files (if there is one file in each folder). I have 3 files in 2 folders. Each fine name is the same in both folders - ex.: file1 in dir 1 file 1 in dir 2, file2 in dir 2 file 2 in dir 2 and etc. I have mentioned above how can I solved the problem with compression of several files inside two folders.

Answer (score 0):

I made a slight change. Not sure why you have 2 x else statements. Copy is down twice.
The change below will show coping in RED.

```
$Source =  "folder1"
$Destination = "folder2"

get-childitem $Source -Recurse | foreach {
#Calculate hash using Algorithm MD5 reference http://www.tomsitpro.com/articles/powershell-file-hash-check,2-880.html
$SrcFile = $_.FullName
$SrcHash = Get-FileHash -Path $SrcFile -Algorithm MD5

$DestFile = $_.Fullname -replace [RegEx]::escape($Source),$Destination
Write-Host
Write-Host "Comparing $SrcFile to $DestFile" -ForegroundColor Yellow

if (Test-Path $DestFile) {
    #Check the hash sum of the file copied
    $DestHash = Get-FileHash -Path $DestFile -Algorithm MD5

    #compare them up
    if ($SrcHash.hash -ne $DestHash.hash) {
        Write-Warning "$SrcFile and $DestFile Files don't match!" 
            Write-Host "Copying $SrcFile to $DestFile" -ForegroundColor Red
        Copy-Item $SrcFile -Destination $DestFile -Force
    } else {
        Write-Host "$SrcFile and $DestFile Files Match" -ForegroundColor Green
    }

} 
}
```